# TTTAttributedLabel, change of color works only the first time controller launches in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsmutableattributedstring, nsattributedstringkey

```
 self.descriptionLbl.text = actionReqdText
    let labelString = self.descriptionLbl.text as! NSString
    let contactRange1 = labelString.range(of: actionString1)
    let contactRange2 = labelString.range(of: actionString2)

    self.descriptionLbl.addLink(to: URL(string: link1), with: contactRange1)
    self.descriptionLbl.addLink(to: URL(string: link2), with: contactRange2)

    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: descriptionLbl.attributedText!)

    if  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height < 900 {
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: HELVETICA_LIGHT, size: 13)!], range: contactRange1)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: HELVETICA_LIGHT, size: 13)!], range: contactRange2)
    } else {
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: HELVETICA_LIGHT, size: 18)!], range: contactRange1)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: HELVETICA_LIGHT, size: 18)!], range: contactRange2)
    }

    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as String as String): UIColor(red: 0.06, green: 0.49, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.0)], range: contactRange1)

    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as String as String): UIColor(red: 0.06, green: 0.49, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.0)], range: contactRange2)

    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue], range: contactRange1)
    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue], range: contactRange2)

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.1 


    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

    descriptionLbl.attributedText = attributedText
```

> I've been trying this code to get a text in green color and with no underline style. It works the first time I launch the view controller. The next time I get to this screen, it is in native blue and underlined. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.descriptionLbl.text = actionReqdText
let labelString = self.descriptionLbl.text as! NSString
let contactRange1 = labelString.range(of: actionString1)
let contactRange2 = labelString.range(of: actionString2)

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: descriptionLbl.attributedText!)

var linkAttributes: [AnyHashable : Any] = [:]
linkAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle] = NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue

if  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height < 900 {
                    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: HELVETICA_LIGHT, size: 13)!], range: contactRange1)
                    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: HELVETICA_LIGHT, size: 13)!], range: contactRange2)
                } else {
                    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: HELVETICA_LIGHT, size: 18)!], range: contactRange1)
                    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: HELVETICA_LIGHT, size: 18)!], range: contactRange2)
                }

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.1 

linkAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor(red: 0.06, green: 0.49, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.0)

linkAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle] = paragraphStyle
self.descriptionLbl.attributedText = attributedText
self.descriptionLbl.linkAttributes = linkAttributes
self.descriptionLbl.addLink(to: URL(string: link1), with: contactRange1)
self.descriptionLbl.addLink(to: URL(string: link2), with: contactRange2)
```

> Implemented the above code by replacing the addAttributes with link attributes and moving the addLinks after adding the attributes. This resolved the issue